# Inserting multiple result sets of a stored procedure into a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure which returns multiple result sets. I am trying to retrieve column value of all results into temp table. Is it possible?

My stored procedure returns columns like below. I have about more than 10 result sets being returned, which each have a `tid` column.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to select `tId`'s to a temp table.

Comment: Or you can create a temp table *before* you call your SP and then have your SP insert directly into the temp table.

Comment: @Dale K, how to create a temp table if the result sets have different schema

Comment: If thats truly the best solution for you, you have to create a super schema which covers all the columns for all the tables. Columns not used by a given resultset will just be null.

Answer (score 0):

You will collect all datasets into one table only if output definition of each rowset will match table schema (not your case), so I would suggest to prepare united dataset inside stored procedure and output it separately or as an output table variable.

```
create procedure proc_multi as
begin
select 1 id;
select 2 id;
end;

create table #t (id int);

insert into #t
    exec proc_multi;

select * from #t;

id
-----------
1
2

(2 rows affected)
```